# How to Use Multithreading script

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I found this Multithreading script at http://www.get-blog.com/?p=189

```
Param($Command = $(Read-Host "Enter the script file"), 
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$ObjectList,
    $InputParam = $Null,
    $MaxThreads = 20,
    $SleepTimer = 200,
    $MaxResultTime = 120,
    [HashTable]$AddParam = @{},
    [Array]$AddSwitch = @()
)

Begin{
    $ISS = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()
    $RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $MaxThreads, $ISS, $Host)
    $RunspacePool.Open()

    If ($(Get-Command | Select-Object Name) -match $Command){
        $Code = $Null
    }Else{
        $OFS = "`r`n"
        $Code = [ScriptBlock]::Create($(Get-Content $Command))
        Remove-Variable OFS
    }
    $Jobs = @()
}

Process{
    Write-Progress -Activity "Preloading threads" -Status "Starting Job $($jobs.count)"
    ForEach ($Object in $ObjectList){
        If ($Code -eq $Null){
            $PowershellThread = [powershell]::Create().AddCommand($Command)
        }Else{
            $PowershellThread = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($Code)
        }
        If ($InputParam -ne $Null){
            $PowershellThread.AddParameter($InputParam, $Object.ToString()) | out-null
        }Else{
            $PowershellThread.AddArgument($Object.ToString()) | out-null
        }
        ForEach($Key in $AddParam.Keys){
            $PowershellThread.AddParameter($Key, $AddParam.$key) | out-null
        }
        ForEach($Switch in $AddSwitch){
            $Switch
            $PowershellThread.AddParameter($Switch) | out-null
        }
        $PowershellThread.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
        $Handle = $PowershellThread.BeginInvoke()
        $Job = "" | Select-Object Handle, Thread, object
        $Job.Handle = $Handle
        $Job.Thread = $PowershellThread
        $Job.Object = $Object.ToString()
        $Jobs += $Job
    }

}

End{
    $ResultTimer = Get-Date
    While (@($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle -ne $Null}).count -gt 0)  {

        $Remaining = "$($($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False}).object)"
        If ($Remaining.Length -gt 60){
            $Remaining = $Remaining.Substring(0,60) + "..."
        }
        Write-Progress `
            -Activity "Waiting for Jobs - $($MaxThreads - $($RunspacePool.GetAvailableRunspaces())) of $MaxThreads threads running" `
            -PercentComplete (($Jobs.count - $($($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False}).count)) / $Jobs.Count * 100) `
            -Status "$(@($($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False})).count) remaining - $remaining" 

        ForEach ($Job in $($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $True})){
            $Job.Thread.EndInvoke($Job.Handle)
            $Job.Thread.Dispose()
            $Job.Thread = $Null
            $Job.Handle = $Null
            $ResultTimer = Get-Date
        }
        If (($(Get-Date) - $ResultTimer).totalseconds -gt $MaxResultTime){
            Write-Error "Child script appears to be frozen, try increasing MaxResultTime"
            Exit
        }
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepTimer

    } 
    $RunspacePool.Close() | Out-Null
    $RunspacePool.Dispose() | Out-Null
}
```

I'm confused as how to use it though. In particular how to use the $ObjectList variable. I would like to use this ping script that I wrote to ping a list of 100,000 machines... But in it's current form it pings about 100 machines a minute. So it would take over 16 hours to complete.

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\Comps.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {

    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1) {   

        "$Computer is Pinging"

        }


    Else {

        "$Computer is not Pinging"

        }

    }
```

Any pointers as to how to integrate the ping script with the multithreading script to yield faster results?

I'm assuming that I would remove the $Computers variable from the ping script, and instead use the $ObjectList variable in the multithreading script. But all of my attempts to do so fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ping hosts asynchronously with [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping], no need to go crazy with runspaces. Moreover it will ping the host once, so it will be way much faster than test-connection.  Below is a sample for a batch of hosts (about 90). I guess it's not a good idea to load 100K at once, probably split it in smaller batches and do one by one.

```
$hosts = "www.facebook.com,www.twitter.com,www.youtu.be,www.google.com,www.youtube.com,www.instagram.com,www.linkedin.com,www.pinterest.com,www.wordpress.com,www.blogspot.com,www.apple.com,www.adobe.com,www.tumblr.com,www.amazon.com,www.vimeo.com,www.flickr.com,www.microsoft.com,www.yahoo.com,www.godaddy.com,www.qq.com,www.vk.com,www.reddit.com,www.baidu.com,www.nytimes.com,www.buydomains.com,www.wp.com,www.statcounter.com,www.jimdo.com,www.blogger.com,www.github.com,www.weebly.com,www.soundcloud.com,www.myspace.com,www.addthis.com,www.theguardian.com,www.cnn.com,www.stumbleupon.com,www.gravatar.com,www.digg.com,www.addtoany.com,www.creativecommons.org,www.paypal.com,www.yelp.com,www.imdb.com,www.huffingtonpost.com,www.feedburner.com,www.issuu.com,www.wixsite.com,www.wix.com,www.dropbox.com,www.forbes.com,www.amazonaws.com,www.washingtonpost.com,www.bluehost.com,www.etsy.com,www.go.com,www.msn.com,www.wsj.com,www.weibo.com,www.fc2.com,www.eventbrite.com,www.parallels.com,www.ebay.com,www.livejournal.com,www.reuters.com,www.taobao.com,www.typepad.com,www.bloomberg.com,www.elegantthemes.com,www.eepurl.com,www.usatoday.com,www.about.com,www.medium.com,www.macromedia.com,www.xing.com,www.bing.com,www.time.com,www.tripadvisor.com,www.aol.com,www.constantcontact.com,www.latimes.com,www.list-manage.com,www.webs.com,www.opera.com,www.live.com,www.bandcamp.com,www.bbc.com,www.businessinsider.com,www.dailymotion.com,www.cpanel.com,www.disqus.com,www.sina.com.cn,www.spotify.com,www.wired.com,www.googleusercontent.com"
$hosts = $hosts -split ","

$tasks = @{}
foreach ($h in $hosts) { $tasks[$h] = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping]::new().SendPingAsync($h)}

Write-Host "Waiting for batch is completed" -NoNewline
while($false -in $tasks.Values.IsCompleted) {sleep -Milliseconds 300; Write-Host "." -NoNewline}

$result = foreach($h in $hosts) {
$r = $tasks[$h].Result
[PSCustomObject]@{
 host = $h
 address = $r.Address.IPAddressToString
 status = if($r.Address.IPAddressToString){$r.Status}else{"Failed"}
 time = $r.RoundtripTime
 bytes = $r.Buffer.Count
 ttl = $r.Options.Ttl
  }
}


$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Hey Mike, this script is pretty impressive. Pings about 5000 machines in a minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This script, which I have adapted from the link and author in the synopsis, has good performance for me.  I have modified it to take not only a range of ip addresses, but also an array of host names.  Because of that, some of the variable names have poor names, but this is not production code so I have not invested in it beyond what I have below.

```
function Global:Ping-IPRange {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Sends ICMP echo request packets to a range of IPv4 addresses between two given addresses.

    .DESCRIPTION
        This function lets you sends ICMP echo request packets ("pings") to 
        a range of IPv4 addresses using an asynchronous method.

        Therefore this technique is very fast but comes with a warning.
        Ping sweeping a large subnet or network with many swithes may result in 
        a peak of broadcast traffic.
        Use the -Interval parameter to adjust the time between each ping request.
        For example, an interval of 60 milliseconds is suitable for wireless networks.
        The RawOutput parameter switches the output to an unformated
        [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply[]].

    .INPUTS
        None
        You cannot pipe input to this funcion.

    .OUTPUTS
        The function only returns output from successful pings.

        Type: System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply

        The RawOutput parameter switches the output to an unformated
        [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply[]].

    .NOTES
        Author  : G.A.F.F. Jakobs
        Created : August 30, 2014
        Version : 6

    .EXAMPLE
        Ping-IPRange -StartAddress 192.168.1.1 -EndAddress 192.168.1.254 -Interval 20

        IPAddress                                 Bytes                     Ttl           ResponseTime
        ---------                                 -----                     ---           ------------
        192.168.1.41                                 32                      64                    371
        192.168.1.57                                 32                     128                      0
        192.168.1.64                                 32                     128                      1
        192.168.1.63                                 32                      64                     88
        192.168.1.254                                32                      64                      0

        In this example all the ip addresses between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254 are pinged using 
        a 20 millisecond interval between each request.
        All the addresses that reply the ping request are listed.

    .EXAMPLE
        Ping-IPRange -HostName "host1"
        Ping-IPRange -HostName @('host1', 'host2')
        Ping-IPRange -HostName @('www.microsoft.com', 'www.google.com')

    .LINK
        http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Fast-asynchronous-ping-IP-d0a5cf0e

    #>
    [CmdletBinding(ConfirmImpact='Low')]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName='range')]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]$StartAddress,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1, ParameterSetName='range')]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]$EndAddress,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName='list')]
        [string[]]$HostName,
        [int]$Interval = 30,
        [Switch]$RawOutput = $false
    )

    $timeout = 2000

    function New-Range ($start, $end) {
        $addrList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

        [byte[]]$BySt = $start.GetAddressBytes()
        [Array]::Reverse($BySt)
        [byte[]]$ByEn = $end.GetAddressBytes()
        [Array]::Reverse($ByEn)
        $i1 = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt32($BySt,0)
        $i2 = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt32($ByEn,0)
        for($x = $i1;$x -le $i2;$x++){
            $ip = ([System.Net.IPAddress]$x).GetAddressBytes()
            [Array]::Reverse($ip)
            $null = $addrList.Add([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($($ip -join '.')))
        }

        ,$addrList
    }

    if ($HostName)
    {
        $IPrange = @($HostName)
    }
    else
    {
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$IPrange = New-Range $StartAddress $EndAddress
    }

    $IpTotal = $IPrange.Count

    Get-Event -SourceIdentifier "ID-Ping*" | Remove-Event
    Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "ID-Ping*" | Unregister-Event

    $index = 0
    foreach ($ip in $IPrange){
        if ($HostName)
        {
            [string]$VarName = "Ping_" + $ip + "_" + [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
        }
        else
        {
            [string]$VarName = "Ping_" + $ip.Address
        }

        New-Variable -Name $VarName -Value (New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping)

        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject (Get-Variable $VarName -ValueOnly) -EventName PingCompleted -SourceIdentifier "ID-$VarName"

        (Get-Variable $VarName -ValueOnly).SendAsync($ip,$timeout,$VarName)

        try{

            $pending = (Get-Event -SourceIdentifier "ID-Ping*").Count

        }catch [System.InvalidOperationException]{
            Write-Verbose "Ping-IPrange : InvalidOperationException" -Verbose
        }
        finally{
            Remove-Variable $VarName
        }

        #$index = [array]::indexof($IPrange,$ip)

        if ($HostName)
        {
            Write-Progress -Activity "Sending ping to" -Id 1 -status $ip -PercentComplete (($index / $IpTotal)  * 100)
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Progress -Activity "Sending ping to" -Id 1 -status $ip.IPAddressToString -PercentComplete (($index / $IpTotal)  * 100)
        }

        Write-Progress -Activity "ICMP requests pending" -Id 2 -ParentId 1 -Status ($index - $pending) -PercentComplete (($index - $pending)/$IpTotal * 100)

        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $Interval

        $index++
    }

    Write-Progress -Activity "Done sending ping requests" -Id 1 -Status 'Waiting' -PercentComplete 100 

    While($pending -lt $IpTotal){

        Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "ID-Ping*" | Out-Null

        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10

        $pending = (Get-Event -SourceIdentifier "ID-Ping*").Count

        Write-Progress -Activity "ICMP requests pending" -Id 2 -ParentId 1 -Status ($IpTotal - $pending) -PercentComplete (($IpTotal - $pending)/$IpTotal * 100)
    }

    if($RawOutput){

        $Reply = Get-Event -SourceIdentifier "ID-Ping*" | ForEach { 
            If($_.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Status -eq "Success"){
                $_.SourceEventArgs.Reply
            }
            Unregister-Event $_.SourceIdentifier
            Remove-Event $_.SourceIdentifier
        }

    }else{
        $events = Get-Event -SourceIdentifier "ID-Ping*"
        $Reply = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

        $i = 0
        foreach ($event in $events) { 
            If($event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Status -eq "Success"){
                if ($HostName)
                {
                    $null = $Reply.Add(
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "HostName" = $HostName[$i]
                            "IPAddress" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Address
                            "Bytes" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Buffer.Length
                            "Ttl" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Options.Ttl
                            "ResponseTime" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.RoundtripTime
                        }
                    )
                }
                else
                {
                    $null = $Reply.Add(
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "IPAddress" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Address
                            "Bytes" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Buffer.Length
                            "Ttl" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.Options.Ttl
                            "ResponseTime" = $event.SourceEventArgs.Reply.RoundtripTime
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            else{
                $addr = ($event.SourceIdentifier -split '_')[1]
                $ip = ((([System.Net.IPAddress]$addr).IPAddressToString).Split('.'))
                [Array]::Reverse($ip)
                $ip = $ip -join '.'

                if ($HostName)
                {
                    $null = $Reply.Add(
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "HostName" = $HostName[$i]
                            "IPAddress" = '0.0.0.0'
                            "Bytes" = -1
                            "Ttl" = -1
                            "ResponseTime" = -1
                        }
                    )
                }
                else
                {
                    $null = $Reply.Add(
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "IPAddress" = $ip
                            "Bytes" = -1
                            "Ttl" = -1
                            "ResponseTime" = -1
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            Unregister-Event $event.SourceIdentifier
            Remove-Event $event.SourceIdentifier
            $i++
        }
    }

    if($Reply -eq $Null){
        Write-Verbose "Ping-IPrange : No ip address responded" -Verbose
    }

    return ,$Reply
}
```