# Pull Server names and ip address and see if they're live

Tags: list, powershell, server, ip-address

I am looking to run a PowerShell script that will pull all servers from AD, show me the FQDN and IP address as well as tell me if the server is pinging.

I have a couple of scripts that do certain parts but would like to get something all in one and am having a hard time doing it.

Ping a list of servers:

```
$ServerName = Get-Content "c:\temp\servers.txt"
foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {
    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet ) {
        "$Server is Pinging "
    } else {
        "$Server not pinging"
    }
}
```

I also have a script to pull all servers from AD which shows server name, FQDN, and OS version:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like '*Windows Server*'} -Properties * |
    select Name, DNSHostName, OperatingSystem
```

Any help in getting a script to show me all servers in my environment with FQDN, IP address and if there live would be appreciated.

Comment: `select Name, DNSHostName, OperatingSystem` -> `select Name, DNSHostName, OperatingSystem, @{n='Online';e={Test-Connection $_.DNSHostName -Count 2 -Quiet}}`

Comment: Beware that depending on the number of servers in your environment doing a sequential sweep will take quite some time. You may want to look into background jobs for running things in parallel.

Comment: see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618904/how-to-use-multithreading-script/53620609#53620609 for one approach to getting ping data.  how you pull names from your AD is another exercise.  putting the two together to suit your needs may be enough for what you are after. Good luck, and welome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: To make your query for the computer accounts even more efficient, don't do `-Properties *` in `Get-ADComputer`. The only property you need that's not returned by the default Get-AdComputer cmdlet is OperatingSystem, so just return that one extra attribute in your query. `Get-AdComputer -filter {...} -Properties OperatingSystem`. Also consider using `-SearchScope` if all your servers are in one OU.

Answer (score 1):

You should only choose desired properties with the `-Property` argument and not pull everything through network with `*`. Also quotes should be used with `-Filter`, not braces.

You can add a calculated property to `Select-Object` and get the value from `Test-NetConnection`:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -like '*Windows Server*'" -Properties dnshostname, operatingsystem |
    Select-Object name, dnshostname, operatingsystem, `
    @{n="PingSucceeded";e={(Test-NetConnection $_.name).PingSucceeded}}
```