# Ping thousands of machines in parallel, saving result to array

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ping

I have the following code. I want to have my pingAll function call the ping workflow so that I can get a list of all machines that are online. I must do this in parallel because of the number of machines I will be querying.

The only problem is that I cannot call `$alive.Add($computer)` inside the workflow because "Method invocation is not supported in a Windows Powershell Workflow".

Since this is the case, how is it possible to save the results from the foreach into an array or data structure of some sort?

```
function pingAll
{    
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties CN | select CN
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$alive = @() #array of online machines
}
workflow ping ($computers)
{
    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers)
    {
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {$alive.Add($computer) }
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954004/how-to-multithread-powershell-ping-script/37955801#37955801 which should be easy to modify to fit your needs.

Comment: @KoryGill I don't exactly see an "easy" way of modifying it. Is there a way to store data obtained from a -parallel loop?

Comment: $Output = Ping $computers

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618904/how-to-use-multithreading-script/53620553#53620553

Comment: @MikeTwc That works great with the default list of sites but how can I convert my $computers into a data type that is supported? I tried typecasting it to a [string] but that didn't work

Comment: You just need array of computer names, I'd do somehting like (Get-ADComputer -filter * -ResultSetSize 10).DNSHostName

Comment: @MikeTwc That worked! Why didn't $computers = (Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties CN | select CN)? Was it not creating an array of strings and instead creating an array of objects that contained a string?

Comment: Because it create an array of PSObject. Actually you can use $computers.CN to get  string array

Comment: @MikeTwc Thanks for all your help! That script is very fast. I can query 20,000 machines in under three minutes